# How not to break your code using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am getting problems to maintain my code readable and understandable, while programming with AJAX.

**Introduction:**

Basic philosophy is quite simple. I call AJAX function to retrieve data from server (`getServerData`). One of its arguments is the `callbackFunc`. When data is loaded, then it is passed to the `callbackFunc`, and this function is evoked.

Here is AJAX routine I use to get data from server:

```
function getServerData(urlAdress, params, callbackFunc, sender,  method){
    if (method !== "GET"){method = "POST";}
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            if (callbackFunc){callbackFunc(xhttp.responseText, sender);}
        }
    };
    if (method == "GET"){
        xhttp.open(method, urlAdress, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
    else {
        xhttp.open(method, urlAdress, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send(params);
    }
}
```

Here is callback routine:

```
do_Select = function(responseText, sender){
 alert(responseText);
}
```

So when I want to load data and then perform something I will use it like this:

```
getServerData("example.com/select.php", someParams, do_Select, this, "POST");
```

**The problem:**

But my headache comes, when my `do_Select` function looks like that:

```
    do_Select = function (responseText, sender) {
            switch (responseText) {
                case "one":
                    if (something1 === something2) {
                        //....
                        getServerData("example.com/select.php", someParams, callback2, this, "POST");
                    } else
                    {
                        //....
                        getServerData("example.com/select.php", someParams, callback3, this, "POST");
                    }

                    break;
                case "two":
                        //....
                        getServerData("example.com/select.php", someParams, callback4, this, "POST");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I have to declare callback functions elsewhere in the code, which makes the programming logic very hard to understand read and debug after time and as the code grows.

Is there a better and more efficient way to make the code more compact?

Comment: Use promises. You can chain function calls instead of nesting them, so the relevant code stays together.

Comment: The [`Promise` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as well as many [promise libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+promise+libraries) have been written in order to make async code readable.

Answer (score 0):

Too easy, simply use anonymous functions:

```
getServerData("example.com/select.php", someParams,function(arg){
    alert(arg);}
, this, "POST");
```

OR use promises:

```
function getServerData(urlAdress, params, sender,  method){
return new Promise(function(callbackFunc){
if (method !== "GET"){method = "POST";}
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        if (callbackFunc){callbackFunc(xhttp.responseText, sender);}
    }
};
if (method == "GET"){
    xhttp.open(method, urlAdress, true);
    xhttp.send();
 }
 else {
    xhttp.open(method, urlAdress, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(params);
  }
 });
}
```

Use it like this:

```
getServerData("example.com",someparams,this,"POST").then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

One word: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Okay, maybe two: [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), to get rid of that horrible XHR code. The end result would look like:

```
fetch(args)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(responseText => {
    // First fetch responded. Now on to the next.
    return (condition1) ? fetch(args)
         : (condition2) ? fetch(args)
         : fetch(args);
  })
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(responseText => {
    // Second fetch, whichever one you returned, responded.
  });
```

Comment: I will check... thanx